# Avoiding duplicates with Apple's Push Notification Service (APNS)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

We referred to Apple's TN2265 (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html) for implementing error handling in our app, which sends push notifications to our users. The documentation suggests that we deal with errors asynchronously, specifically:

> If you get six bytes back, that's an error response that you can check for the response code and the ID of the notification that caused the error. You'll need to send every notification following that one again.

Is it the case that in a sequence of notifications, if one fails then all notifications following it are guaranteed to have failed? If not, then how does one avoid duplicate sends of the same notification to a given device?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in that case all the notifications following it are guaranteed to not even be processed by the APNS server.

When APNS detects an invalid message, it writes the error response to the socket and closes the connection. Until you receive that error response, it's possible that you already sent more messages to Apple on the same socket. All of them won't reach Apple. Once you create a new socket you should resend all of them.

There is no risk of duplicates.